# Recover content from a deleted user and assign ownership to other user

Tags: userpoints

There is a user that needs to be deleted but I need to keep his content. I want to know if there's a way to transfer the ownership of all of his content (nodes, userpoints, etc.) to another user? I tried [views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), but there is no option there.

I know that I can delete the user and keep the content and give it to the Drupal anonymous user, but it´s possible to set up an specific user?

Comment: @fullerja I tried both options but didn´t worked for me.

Comment: What didn't work? Is it because you're looking to transfer all user data, not just node ownership?

Comment: @ShawnConn Yes, that´s what I´m trying to do, transfer all data from user x to user z, could it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Transferring ownership of nodes is a part of Drupal core's functionality. Outside of that, any other contrib module has to provide that functionality itself; Drupal core doesn't have a concept data ownership for contrib module data.

I've rarely seen a contrib module implement a data ownership transfer feature. For popular modules they might exist but it's not a given. For example, with userpoints there submodule called userpoints_donations in the [User Points Contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) project. However, it covers the use case of ***one user giving to another***, not transfership from an account set to expire.

You might be able to do this on a per module basis if you look at the data tables each module stores in its **.install** file. It would be pretty easy to look at each table for a `uid` column and perform a SQL UPDATE statement that changes any uid value from X to Y. If you know all the modules in question (with their respective data tables), it's quite feasible to build [your own custom VBO operation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067) that would automatically do the SQL queries for you.